# Switch between request.security() and request.security_lower_tf()?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I understand that request.security() is optimized for higher timeframe data calls and for lower the request.security_lower_tf().
However in the inputs section i want to show only one input.timeframe and code the strategy to toggle between higher and lower security calls by itself automatically.

```
longMTF_HT = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, inputTimeframe, longCondition[1], barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
shortMTF_HT =  request.security(syminfo.tickerid, inputTimeframe, shortCondition[1], barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)

longMTF_LT = request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid, inputTimeframe, longCondition)
shortMTF_LT = request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid, inputTimeframe, shortCondition)

longMTF = timeframe.period < inputTimeframe ? longMTF_HT : longMTF_LT
shortMTF = timeframe.period < inputTimeframe ? shortMTF_HT: shortMTF_LT
```

**The above code returns the error:**

```
line 39: Cannot call 'operator ?:' with argument 'expr2'='shortMTF_LT'. An argument of 'bool[]' type was used but a 'series bool' is expected
```

**Looking for a solution**

Answer (score 3):

It's because they return you different values. Unfortunatelly it is not documented well by TradingView.
`request.security()` - will return you eg. a `close` **value** from a higher timeframe in that this simple value fits easily into your timeframe | *series float*
`request.security_ltf()` - will return you **an array of** `close` **values** that, all grouped together, will fit into your current timeframe | *array of series float*
So less/equal amount of imported data vs. grouped, more detailed ltf data.

For ltf imports you are going to need some array operations/loops to process everything.